# Can I have aligned bottomCenter instead of topLeft for performing animateContentSize?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have this code that perform "animateContentSize" with text size changes.

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        var message by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        Box (Modifier
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = tween(2000)
            ),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter){
            Text(message)
        }

        Button(onClick = {
            message = newText('O')
        }) {
            Text("Click Me")
        }

    }
```

I'm expecting it to animate with the content aligned BottomCenter. However it is always aligned TopLeft (as you see, when it shrink, the text went up to TopLeft and then slowly moved toward Center.)

[image]

Is there a way to make it aligned BottomCenter, so the Text won't fly up as the size shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API currently doesn't support it. Could you file a feature request for specifying content alignment in `animateContentSize`?

Answer (score -1):

To align views `BottomCenter`, you can add `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom` to your `Column`

```
 Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {}
```

Comment: It's not solving the problem, unfortunately, but just bringing the button to the bottom.